# Does the data state stay persistent while executing a single query in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, multithreading, transactions, locking

Does the data state stay persistent while executing a single query in Postgresql?
Example. I have a query:

```
Select * From t1; Select * From SomeSlowView; Select * From t1;
```

Does the first `Select` give always the same result as the third one? Imagine another query is running in parallel:

```
Update t1 Set x = x + 1;
```

or

```
Insert t1 ...;
```

Can I get different data whith the first `Select` and the third `Select` in the first query? If not, can transactions help?

```
Begin;
Select * From t1; Select * From SomeSlowView; Select * From t1;
Commit;
```

Do I need to exlpicitly lock `t1`?

```
Lock Table t1;
Select * From t1; Select * From SomeSlowView; Select * From t1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on the transaction isolation level you are using.

With the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, the first and the second query on `t1` will have a different snapshot, so they can receive different results.

If you use the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level (or a higher one), PostgreSQL will use the same snapshot for all statements in a transaction, so the both queries on `t1` will see the same result.

If you need that kind of consistency, use `REPEATABLE READ`. Don't lock tables. Even if you used the appropriate lock level (`LOCK t1 IN SHARE MODE`) instead of `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` as you do, that lock will be bad for concurrency, and, what is worse, it may well prevent autovacuum from cleaning up on `t1`, which can lead to serious problems.

Comment: What isolation level do I need to get "1" as a result of the last `select` for this query: `Update t1 set x=1; Select * From SomeSlowView; Select * From t1;`? Imagine I have `Update t1 Set x = x + 1;` running in parallel.

Comment: No isolation level will do that, because it cannot be. the transactions would lock with each other. Either you'll end up with a deadlock, or you'll se the results from the concurrent query (if you use `READ COMMITTED`), or you end up with a serialization error (if you use `REPEATABLE READ`). It looks like you are just playing around, or is there an actula problem behind your questions?

Comment: my actual problem [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573252/how-to-implement-cache-table-in-postgresql)