# How to implement cache table in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I have multiple queries that need heavy calculations. I want to cache these calculations in a table. I have created the table `Permissions: Cache` to store a cache. Then I have created the function `Permissions: Access Cache` to access this cache and the procedure `Permissions: Cache Persons Access Level For Operation` to fill the cache. And I run this procedure every time before I need to use this cache. The code looks like this:

```
Create Function "Permissions: Access Cache"(_User uuid, _Securable uuid)
Returns Table ("Object" uuid, "Access Level" int) As
$$
Begin
Return Query
(
    Select "Cache"."Object", "Cache"."Access Level"
    From "Permissions: Cache" "Cache"
    Where "Cache"."User" = _User
    And "Cache"."Securable" = _Securable
);
End
$$
language 'plpgsql';

Create Procedure "Permissions: Cache Persons Access Level For Operation"(_User uuid, _Operation uuid)
language plpgsql
As $$
begin
Insert Into "Permissions: Cache" ("User", "Securable", "Object", "Access Level")
Select _User, _Operation, "Persons"."id", "Permissions"."Access Level"
From "Persons"
-- the "Permissions: Object Access Level For Person Operation" is slow, I want to cache it's result
Left Join Lateral "Permissions: Object Access Level For Person Operation"(_User, "id", _Operation) "Permissions" On True
Where "Persons"."id" Not In (Select "Object" From "Permissions: Access Cache"(_User, _Operation));
End; $$;
```

It adds new records to the cache for each row in the main table `Persons`.

And I have triggers to invalidate the cache if related some tables were updated. So the cache will be re-filled next time I call the procedure.

```
Create Or Replace Function "Permissions: Clear Cache"() Returns Trigger As
$$
Begin
Delete From "Permissions: Cache";
Return Null;
End;
$$ Language plpgsql;

Create Or Replace Trigger "Permissions: Clear Cache: Users: Group Entries"
After Insert Or Update Or Delete On "Users: Group Entries"
Execute Function "Permissions: Clear Cache"();
```

The usage of the cache looks like this (let's call it Q1):

```
Call "Permissions: Cache Persons Access Level For Operation"(u, o);

Select ...
From "Persons"
Inner Join "Permissions: Access Cache"(u, o) Cache On Cache."Object" = "Persons"."id"
Where Cache."Access Level" > 0
```

**The question is how cat I use this cache in a multithreading environment?**

First. I want to have a cache with a single row per distinct User+Securable+Object values.  But when I run multiple queries like Q1 at the same time, I get multiple rows with the same User+Securable+Object.

Second. I want my Q1 to have values in the cache all the time when running `Select`s after `Call` event some trigger is trying to clear the cache while Q1 is running. Imagine Q1 calls the procedure (first statement in the query) and then other transaction runs `Delete From "Permissions: Cache"`. In this case I want to have "Permissions: Cache" filled while running select (second statement in Q1).

PS. I think adding `Lock Table "Permissions: Cache"` in front of Q1 works for me, but I've read that locking tables is not a good way.

Comment: You could use a materialized view instead with a specific update policy. If you don't need information updated up to the millisecond, maybe you can schedule automatic updates every minute or so.

Comment: Why would you delete every record in the table, and create new records for just a single user? Without knowing all the details, it looks like a complex solution for a simple problem. Locking a table would destroy any concurrency. If you do, you can close this question because there won't be any multithreading anymore.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Just imagine I clear the cache (delete all records) for another reason.